# Combining multiple values (character class) in R using c()

Tags: r

I was doing bioinformatics analysis when I needed to combine a set of values The values have similar names like `pruned_11`, `pruned_12`, and each of them consists of several characters.

The values look like this:
[image: The values look like this]

I have tried `combine = c(list = ls(pattern = "^pruned_"))`but it returned a value with only the "pruned_" names in it.

I could also use `combine = c(pruned_12, pruned_13, pruned_14, pruned_15...)`to get what I needed, but it would take too much time if I had to type all 23 chromosomes for every single analysis. Is there any way I could conbine them without typing them each? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mget` to get a `list` of variables from their names

```
combine = mget(ls(pattern = "^pruned_"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but the result was slightly different than I expected. The pruned_12, pruned_13 were all values, and I expect the combination to be a value as well, just like the pruned_1_11. `mget` resulted in a list, and was placed in the "data" window instead of "value".

Comment: If you want to convert the list into a single character vector, `unlist()` it.

Comment: I see! That was so foolish of me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `ls()`. Try this:

```
combine <- c(sapply(ls(pattern = "^pruned_"), function(name) eval(parse(text = name))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Like above, this resulted in a list in the "Data" window. I was trying to reach a result that was also put into the "values" window, like pruned_1_11. Actually I got pruned_1_11 by using c(pruned_1, pruned_2, ... pruned_11)